# Joint distribution - question on limits - find $k$ so that $f(x, y) = kxy$ will be a pdf, where $1 < x < y < 2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find $k$ so that $f(x, y) = kxyI_{1 < x < y < 2}$ will be a pdf.

I used the limits of integration as x to 2 for y and 1 to y for x. Although my limits for x are correct, they are wrong for y. I drew the diagram as well. The answer says the limits of y are 1 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, a diagram or graph is the way to go. This is a triangle. Now it depends on which order you integrate, but you can solve $$\int_1^2\int_1^y kxy dxdy=1$$ or $$\int_1^2\int_x^2 kxy dydx=1$$.

I like to think about these problems like this:

1) First draw the region (triangle here, with the right angle in the top left).

2) For the "outside" integral (in the first one that is respect to $y$), what is the range of this variable (will not depend on any other variable).

3) Now, for the inside integral, (in the first one that is respect to $x$) what boundaries will you hit if you draw a line in its direction or parallel to that axis (the x-axis) that is within your specified boundary (Here that line starts at 1 and stops at y).

Sometimes, you may only know how to evaluate both integrals if you choose a specific ordering.

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared so many of the doubts that I had accumulated over some days! Just a question - it shouldn't matter whether we do dydx or dxdy?

Comment: You will get the same answer using either integral I presented. Integrating $dydx$ vs $dxdy$ is what makes the bounds different.

Comment: I did it both ways, got the same answer! Thank you so much. I hope this answer receives more views so that many other students could benefit from such a concise and clear explanation.